# polyfiller number is not working in IE

Tags: javascript

When I implement this https://jsfiddle.net/UC6tG/522/ in my local it is not working.

What would be the issue?

I would like to use number spinner in IE...

**HTML**

```
 <head>
     <script type='text/javascript' src="polyfiller.js"></script>    
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" /> 
         <script  type='text/javascript'>
    webshims.setOptions('forms-ext', {
        replaceUI: 'auto',
        types: 'number'
    });
    webshims.polyfill('forms forms-ext');
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="number" value="1000" min="0" step="0.01" data-number-to-fixed="2" data-number-stepfactor="100" class="currency" id="c1" />
    </body>
```

Comment: "is not working" is not a good problem description. What is it supposed to do, what's it doing instead? Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: It also helps to link to the homepage of the shim... without it, I can't even tell what it is supposed to do.